# page not rendering in IE8 because of SCRIPT1010 and SCRIPT 5022 errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8, gulp

I used for Gulp for generating the one minified `App.min.js` file for all the js files in my project.
When I use this `App.min.js` in my project for testing, Html pages are rendering perfectly in Chrome,firefox, IE9,10 , But HTML pages are not rendering in IE 8 and it is showing error in console,

Console Errors:

> SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier
>   File: app.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 8364
>   SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$injector/modulerr?p0=kp.mydoctor.empanelment&p1=%5B%24injector%3Anomod%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.28
>   File: angular.min.js, Line: 33, Column: 487

What exactly is the issue ?

Comment: If I had to guess your Angular isn't minsafe.  Minify everything except angular itself and you'll probably get a better error back in console.

Comment: I found the issue, As the issue is only in IE8. The root cause is because i tried to use the reserve words in IE7/8. i used myobject.catch method in my code which i shouldn't use because catch is the reserved word